# Rails routing error with namespaced items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-2

We've got a rails app that keeps producing an error that we can't track down. The problem seems to lie with the routing but we're not sure what is happening. Out routes file looks like:

```
  ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
    # Default
    map.home '', :controller => "home"

    # Admin

    map.admin_home 'admin', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'index'
    map.admin_login 'admin/login', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'login'
    map.admin_reminder 'admin/forgot', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'reminder'
    map.namespace :admin do |admin|
      admin.resources :bookings,
        :collection => {
          :archive => :get, :reports => :get, :calendar => :get,
          :step_1 => :any, :step_1a => :any, :step_2 => :any, :step_3 => :any, :confirmation => :any }
      admin.resources :events,
        :member => { :status => :get }
      admin.resources :blogs,
        :collection => { :archive => :get }
      admin.resources :blog_replies,
        :member => { :publish => :get }
      admin.resources :minutes,
        :collection => { :archive => :get }
      admin.resources :businesses
      admin.resources :business_categories
      admin.resources :users
      admin.resources :pricings
      admin.backups 'backups', :controller => 'admin/backups'
      admin.download_backup 'backups/download', :controller => 'admin/backups', :action => 'download'
    end
    map.admin 'admin/:action', :controller => 'admin/admin'

    map.connect 'members', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'redirect_to_index'
    map.connect 'members/login', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'redirect_to_index'
    map.connect 'account', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'redirect_to_index'
    map.connect 'account/login', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'redirect_to_index'
    map.connect 'home', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'redirect_to_index'
    map.connect 'home/login', :controller => 'admin/admin', :action => 'redirect_to_index'

    map.blog 'blog/:permalink', :controller => 'blogs', :action => 'show'
    map.connect 'blog/:id', :controller => 'blogs', :action => 'show'
    map.connect 'book-online', :controller => 'bookings', :action => 'step_1'
    map.connect 'book-online/:action', :controller => 'bookings'
    # Defaults
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
    map.connect "*anything", :controller => "public", :action => "unknown_request"
  end
```

We have a set of public controllers in app/controllers and a set of admin controllers in app/controllers/admin. The issue we keep seeing is when a user goes to a url like admin/bookings, admin/bookings/step_1 or admin/events. Sometimes the urls work perfectly but other times I can see from the log file that something like the following happens:

```
ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to index):
```

Other times we'll get something like:

```
Processing EventsController#index (for [filtered] at 2009-01-21 10:54:38) [GET]
Session ID: [filtered]
Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"admin/events"}
Rendering template within layouts/public
Rendering events/index
Completed in 0.00863 (115 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00338 (39%) | DB: 0.00000 (0%) | 200 OK [http://www.gresfordtrust.org/admin/events]
```

from the last example you can see that the url requested was `admin/events` which should have hit the `#index` in `Admin::EventsController` but instead it renders the `#index` action in `EventsController`.

We're running the app with Rails 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a configured route for EventsController, so your error is happening because some request is falling down to the default route, `map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'`
.

This is happening because someone/something is sending a request of an HTTP method that isn't configured for your AdminEventsController.  Your `admin.resources :events, :member => { :status => :get }` will match the following requests:

```
GET /admin/events
GET /admin/events/<id>
GET /admin/events/<id>/status
POST /admin/events
PUT /admin/events/<id>
DELETE /admin/events/<id>
```

Anything else would fall through to the default route.  So if you're seeing those `ActionController::UnknownAction` on this controller look for requests that are using the wrong HTTP method.

The source of your bizarre log message is almost certainly a request that was something like this:

```
GET /admin/events/index
```

The solution is to get rid of that default route entirely and ensure you're adding `resource[s]` routes for all the controllers in the right place.